# jQuery AJAX and JSON format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a webservice that expects to receive JSON, like so:

```
{"first_name":"test","last_name":"teste","email":"moi@someplace.com","mobile":"+44 22 2222 2222", "password":"testing"}
```

My AJAX call in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            first_name: $("#namec").val(),
            last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
            email: $("#emailc").val(),
            mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
            password: $("#passwordc").val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to check the format in which my data is being sent? I'm supposedly not sending correct JSON to the server (that is the first step in validation).

Is my jQuery code sending valid JSON or did I miss something?

Comment: Copy your JSON before sending it to the URL and paste it in jsonlint.com

Comment: Are you hitting the breakpoint when call to method?

Comment: What would you get if you put your json in a variable and use `console.log()` with that?

Comment: you could try to set the ajax call to a file you created yourself to  see if the data you send is correct.

Comment: use Fiddler, It will help you record all the HTTP and HTTPS traffic that passes between your computer and the Internet.  http://fiddler2.com/features

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You aren't actually sending JSON. You are passing an object as the `data`, but you need to stringify the object and pass the string instead.

Your `dataType: "json"` only tells jQuery that you want it to parse the returned JSON, it does not mean that jQuery will automatically stringify your request data.

Change to:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            first_name: $("#namec").val(),
            last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
            email: $("#emailc").val(),
            mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
            password: $("#passwordc").val()
        }),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
});
```

Comment: So what is the identifier here?

Comment: There is no identifier, the content type is `application/json` so the HTTP request body should be the raw JSON, with no identifier.

Comment: I am so habitual to Angular and other frameworks that I forget, I need to stringify JSON data first. Frameworks have spoiled me. jQuery keeps you on ground.

Answer (score 14):

I never had any luck with that approach.  I always do this (hope this helps):

```
var obj = {};

obj.first_name = $("#namec").val();
obj.last_name = $("#surnamec").val();
obj.email = $("#emailc").val();
obj.mobile = $("#numberc").val();
obj.password = $("#passwordc").val();
```

Then in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are sending the data as typical POST values, which look like this:

```
first_name=somename&last_name=somesurname
```

If you want to send data as json you need to create an object with data and stringify it.

```
data: JSON.stringify(someobject)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
       data__value = JSON.stringify(
       {
           first_name: $("#namec").val(),
           last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
           email: $("#emailc").val(),
           mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
           password: $("#passwordc").val()
       })
   },
   success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   },
   error: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   }
});
```

**(RU)**
На сервере ваши данные можно получить как - $_POST['data__value'];
Например для получения значения first_name на сервере, нужно написать:

**(EN)**
On the server, you can get your data as - $_POST ['data__value'];
For example, to get the first_name value on the server, write:

```
$test = json_decode( $_POST['data__value'] );
echo $test->first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string. You are sending from JavaScript object to the  JSON object

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
```