# AJAX POST data not being completely sent to server

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm uploading a CSV (65KB) through a form on my site, parsing it with [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) and then POSTing it with ajax to my server:

```
console.log(csv)
// if everything is ok, send via AJAX to process with PHP
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/batch_objects.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'Data': csv},
    success: function(result){
        $("#batchResult").html(result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        $("#batchResult").html(result);
    },
});
```

In the console, I can see that the CSV is properly uploaded and parsed - it confirms that all the rows (435 of them) are set in the `csv` var.  On the server side I've got a quick script to check things out:

```
<?php
    $csv = $_POST['Data'];
    echo count($csv);
?>
```

However on the server side I'm only getting 143 of the rows (the output of the echo statement), instead of all 435.

I've tried setting `php_value post_max_size 20M` in my .htaccess but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Can you see the actual post request in FireBug or something simillar? You should see if the data is passed complete to the server script there.

Comment: You're sending it as text in a parameter rather than a file.

Comment: Looking at the actual POST request (Chrome developer tools -> Network tab -> Headers), I can see that all the information is being sent in the header

Comment: How many characters is the text you're putting in the 'Data' parameter?

Comment: 64,988 characters (hence the 65KB)

Comment: I think you can use `phpinfo()` to verify that the `post_max_size` is actually being set successfully. Also, do you know if it's giving you the 1st row through the 143rd row or some section in between or at the end?

Comment: It's the first 143 rows; post_max_size is being properly set.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed things for me (found inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426295/1153897)):

```
// get our data together
var postData = {};
postData.Table = table;
postData.Action = action;
postData.Data = csv;

// if everything is ok, send via AJAX to process with PHP
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/batch_objects.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function(result){
        $("#batchResult").html(result);
        console.log("Success " + result);
    },
    failure: function(result) {
        $("#batchResult").html('ERROR: ' + result);
        console.log('Eror ' + result);
    },
});
```

Then on the sever side you can access the POST data with:

```
$post_data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```