# how to send ajax request with get parameter and post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i tried this way but geting  a bad request

```
  var id = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
     $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'video/ratings?sessionId='+id+'',
        data:{"videoId":"5757e6e41b0a244b256ac1d7","rating":"5"},
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data); 
        } 
     }

 );
```

> these are inputs i have given with
>
> ```
> (required)queryurl:/video/ratings?sessionId=CqqAfowuZLzXHyViPaYzzyOU3dGPCFaG
> input:{"videoId":"5757e6e41b0a244b256ac1d7","rating":"5"}
> ```

Comment: check with your url

Comment: what is the actual request that is being generated to the network?

Comment: this url is right , if i give a wrong  sessionid as request , it says 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: are you using a php for backend?

Comment: 401 means server had received the request but no permission is accepted from that.

Comment: i have give with a project with node js as backend

Comment: ya @happycoding i mean if i give wrong session id im getting error if give correct sessionid im getting the error

Comment: In all ajax call you need a session id right?

Comment: @MohiIndharan, then why don't you pass session id in to the Header , like this: `$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {'Authorization': api_key, 'site': site} });`

Comment: bad request might mean that you are not sending all the parameters to the server, that it expects. What does server log tell you.

Comment: @MohiIndharan , put it in to the comman file and include that comman file in to all the pages , so you don't need to put this header into all your ajax request , all ajax consider this header

Answer (score 0):

try below code , it is work for me.

```
 var id = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
         $.ajax({
            headers: {'session_id': id}
            method:'POST',
            url:'video/ratings/',
            data:{"videoId":"5757e6e41b0a244b256ac1d7","rating":"5"},
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data); 
            } 
         });
```

Comment: so... you are converting query parameter to be part of the path? how does it conform to the original code?

Comment: i am using a PHP  ,in backend i code like this for get url:
`$app->get('/video/:field1/:field2','authenticate', function($id, $field) {`

Comment: ya @Vladimir  i'm using the correct path, is there some other fault in my codde

Comment: @MohiIndharan your requests should correspond to what your server expects. The question is how are you reading the request on the server. Are you expecting JSON or uri-encodded form? Are you expecting any session variables as cookies, etc.

Comment: @MohiIndharan , i change in to the my answer ,have a look

Comment: @VladimirM , `$headers = apache_request_headers();` , in this you can get all the header which is with your request

Comment: @chiragpatel thanks :). but the question was from a bit different perspective. Now HOW, but how he is using this information.

Comment: @MohiIndharan then you might want to specify the content type as: contentType: "application/json",

Comment: see this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426199/jquery-ajax-and-json-format

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
     $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'video/ratings?sessionId='+id+'',
        data:{videoId:"5757e6e41b0a244b256ac1d7",rating:5},
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data); 
        } 
     }
```

);