# AJAX Post Showing An Error when Try to Upgrade jQuery Version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a lot of radio element which have different names and also values. And when I click the radio, it will send to server with AJAX method.

**AJAX METHOD :**

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/myproject/ajax_url",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#my-form").serialize(),
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(){}
    });
});
```

Previously I was used jQuery version **2.2.4** and it works fine, but when I try to change it with jQuery version **3.1.1** it showing an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: (o.dataType || "*").toLowerCase is not a function

I'm sure that what I type on server is not wrong (because I never changing my server code), the error just showing when I try to upgrade my jQuery version. Your solution might help me a lot :)

Comment: dataType: `JSON` should be enclosed by quotes.

Comment: `dataType: "JSON"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with [`JSON` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

> The JSON object contains methods for parsing JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and converting values to JSON. It can't be called or constructed, and aside from its two method properties it has no interesting functionality of its own.

#### jQuery 2.x.x

It trims `dataType` and then returns string type `[Object JSON]` which is fine--string. `jQuery.trim` saves the day.

```
// Extract dataTypes list
s.dataTypes = jQuery.trim(s.dataType || "*").toLowerCase().match(rnotwhite) || [""];
// ------------------^^^^
```

#### jQuery 3.x.x

They removed `$.trim` and since you passed `JSON` which is defined (otherwise, OR operator `||` would pass string `*`.

```
// Extract dataTypes list
s.dataTypes = (s.dataType || "*").toLowerCase().match(rnothtmlwhite) || [""];
```

#### Fix

Enclose `JSON` by quotes so you string rather than an object. `dataType` accepts strings.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/myproject/ajax_url",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#my-form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', // lowercase is always preferered though jQuery does it, too.
        success: function(){}
});
```

Comment: I did not read the changelogs about this so i don't really know. But thanks for your answer :) My bad for missing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will get the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426199/jquery-ajax-and-json-format). There is an syntax error in the parameter dataType. The value should be with double quotes. Hope it will get you the solution.